# Tap to swipe on Android

Tags: android

I am looking for an Android application that can display 4 buttons on top of any application's window:

- 1 button to simulate a swipe-up
- 1 button to simulate a swipe-down
- 1 button to simulate a swipe-left
- 1 button to simulate a swipe-right

If possible:

- the location of the buttons should be configurable
- free

Comment: If anyone has any idea

Comment: please add an answer.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is it for people who have difficulties performing a swipe gesture?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I am playing a 2D shoot-’em-ups game (viz. Sky Force 2014) that uses swipes to control a vessel. I would prefer to touch a button instead as it is faster and causes less strain on the arms.